CORS Policy Error with React Frontend and Flask Backend When Uploading Multiple Images
Actually I have made frontend in reactJs and backend in python flask(consuming a cnn model for some predictions).When i send like 5 to 6 images as my request, then it is working fine but when i sent 10 to 15 images and some time is exhausting then it is giving error like,although i have setup Cors in my code given below :
192.168.151.24/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.151.24:2222/upload-images' from origin 'http://192.168.151.24:1111' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.Understand this error
App.js:177 Error uploading files: po {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}code: "ERR_NETWORK"config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(3), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}message: "Network Error"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}stack: "AxiosError: Network Error\n    at u.onerror (http://192.168.151.24:1111/static/js/main.e4ed8eb8.js:2:404852)\n    at La.request (http://192.168.151.24:1111/static/js/main.e4ed8eb8.js:2:412324)\n    at async http://192.168.151.24:1111/static/js/main.e4ed8eb8.js:2:441003"[[Prototype]]: Error
overrideMethod @ console.js:288
(anonymous) @ App.js:177
Show 1 more frame
Show lessUnderstand this error
:2222/upload-images:1 
        
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

My react Code :
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { PrimeReactProvider } from 'primereact/api';
import { Toast } from 'primereact/toast';
import { FileUpload } from 'primereact/fileupload';
import { ProgressBar } from 'primereact/progressbar';
import { Button } from 'primereact/button';
import { Tooltip } from 'primereact/tooltip';
import { Tag } from 'primereact/tag';
import { InputSwitch } from 'primereact/inputswitch';
import './App.scss';
import axios from 'axios';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import LinearProgress from '@mui/material/LinearProgress';
import { getCurrentTimestamp, mapRequest } from './UtilityFunctions/pathFunctions';

function App() {
  const toast = useRef(null);
  const [totalSize, setTotalSize] = useState(0);
  const fileUploadRef = useRef(null);
  const [folderPath, setFolderPath] = useState('');
  const [uploadMethod, setUploadMethod] = useState(false);
  const [loading,setLoading] =useState(false);
  // true for "Upload Method", false for "Choose Folder Method"
  const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 50 *1024 * 1024;
  const URL = 'http://192.168.151.24:2222'
  // const URL = 'http://localhost:5000'
  const FIXED_PATH = 'D:\\V2_SourceCode\\attributesdetection\\similar-image-clustering-main\\random';
  useEffect(()=>{
    setUploadMethod(uploadMethod)
  },[uploadMethod])
  const onTemplateSelect = (e) => {
    let _totalSize = totalSize;
    let files = e.files;
    let exceeded = false;

    // Calculate total size of selected files
    Object.keys(files).forEach((key) => {
      _totalSize += files[key].size || 0;
      if (_totalSize > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
        exceeded = true;
      }
    });

    if (exceeded) {
      toast.current.show({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Total file size exceeds 50 MB limit for upload feature, use choose folder method for bulk upload !!' });
      fileUploadRef.current.clear(); // Clear selected files if size exceeds limit
    } else {
      setTotalSize(_totalSize);
    }
  };

  const onTemplateUpload = (e) => {
    let _totalSize = 0;

    e.files.forEach((file) => {
      _totalSize += file.size || 0;
    });

    setTotalSize(_totalSize);
    toast.current.show({ severity: 'info', summary: 'Success', detail: 'File Uploaded' });
  };

  const onTemplateRemove = (file, callback) => {
    setTotalSize(totalSize - file.size);
    callback();
  };

  const onTemplateClear = () => {
    setTotalSize(0);
  };

  const headerTemplate = (options) => {
    const { className, chooseButton, uploadButton, cancelButton } = options;
    const value = totalSize / 500000;
    const formattedValue = fileUploadRef && fileUploadRef.current ? fileUploadRef.current.formatSize(totalSize) : '0 B';

    return (
      <div className={className} style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        {/* {chooseButton} */}
        <label style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}>{'Already fixed Folder Method'}</label>
        <InputSwitch
          checked={uploadMethod}
          onChange={(e) => setUploadMethod(e.value)}
          style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}
        />
        <label style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}>{'Upload Method'}</label>

        {uploadMethod ? (
          chooseButton
        ) : null}
        {uploadMethod && cancelButton}
        {uploadMethod && <div className="flex align-items-center gap-3 ml-auto">
          <span>{formattedValue} / 50 MB</span>
          <ProgressBar value={value} showValue={false} style={{ width: '10rem', height: '12px' }}></ProgressBar>
        </div>}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const itemTemplate = (file, props) => {
    return (
      uploadMethod && <div className="flex align-items-center flex-wrap pb-5">
        <div className="flex align-items-center" style={{ width: '40%' }}>
          <img alt={file.name} role="presentation" src={file.objectURL} width={100} />
          <span className="flex flex-column text-left ml-3">
            {file.name}
            <small>{new Date().toLocaleDateString()}</small>
          </span>
        </div>
        <Tag value={props.formatSize} severity="warning" className="px-3 py-2" />
        <Button type="button" icon="pi pi-times" className="p-button-outlined p-button-rounded p-button-danger ml-auto" onClick={() => onTemplateRemove(file, props.onRemove)} />
      </div>
    );
  };

  const emptyTemplate = () => {
    console.log(uploadMethod)
    return uploadMethod ? (
      <div className="flex align-items-center flex-column">
        <i className="pi pi-image mt-3 p-5" style={{ fontSize: '5em', borderRadius: '50%', backgroundColor: 'var(--surface-b)', color: 'var(--surface-d)' }}></i>
        <span style={{ fontSize: '1.2em', color: 'var(--text-color-secondary)' }} className="my-5">
          Drag and Drop Image Here
        </span>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div style={{'display' : 'flex','flexDirection':'column','flexWrap':'nowrap','alignItems':'center','justifyContent':'space-around','gap' : '5rem'}}>
      <div>
        Fixed Path is :  {FIXED_PATH}    
      </div>
            <input
            type="button"
            className='btn btn-success ms-5'
            defaultValue={'Click here to recieve result for fixed folder path'}
            onClick={()=>handlePathSubmit()}
            disabled={loading}
            />
            </div>
    
    ); // If not uploadMethod, return null or alternative content
  };
  

  const handleImagesSubmit = async () => {
    if (fileUploadRef.current) {
      const files = fileUploadRef.current.getFiles();
      if(files.length<1){
        return;
      }
      const formData = new FormData();
      if (!uploadMethod) {
        formData.append('folderPath', folderPath); // Add folder path to form data if using "Choose Folder Method"
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        formData.append('images', files[i]);
      }
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        // mapRequest('/upload-images')
        const response = await axios.post(`${URL}/upload-images`, formData, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
       
          },
          maxContentLength: 1000 * 1024 * 1024, // 1000 MB
          maxBodyLength: 1000 * 1024 * 1024, // 1000 MB
          responseType: 'blob', // Set response type to blob to handle file download
        });
        fileUploadRef.current.clear();
        setTotalSize(0); 
        // Create a URL for the downloaded file
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', `predictions_${getCurrentTimestamp()}.xlsx`);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading files:', error);
      } finally{
        setLoading(false)
      }
    }
  };
  const handlePathSubmit = async ()=>{
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('path',FIXED_PATH);
      const response = await axios.post(`${URL}/uploadpath`,formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
   
        },
        responseType: 'blob',
      });

      // Create a URL for the downloaded file
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute('download', `predictions_${getCurrentTimestamp()}.xlsx`);
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading files:', error);
    } finally{
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }

  const chooseOptions = { icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-images', iconOnly: true, className: 'custom-choose-btn p-button-rounded p-button-outlined' };
  const uploadOptions = { icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-cloud-upload', iconOnly: true, className: 'custom-upload-btn p-button-success p-button-rounded p-button-outlined' };
  const cancelOptions = { icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-times', iconOnly: true, className: 'custom-cancel-btn p-button-danger p-button-rounded p-button-outlined' };

  return (
    <PrimeReactProvider>
      <div className="App">
        {loading && 
          <div className='loadingScreen'>
            <div className='loader'>
              <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
                <LinearProgress color="success" />
                <LinearProgress color="success" />
              </Box>
            </div>
            <div className='blockArea'>
              <span>
                Predicting the Values...
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>}
        <Toast ref={toast}></Toast>

        <Tooltip target=".custom-choose-btn" content="Choose" position="bottom" />
        <Tooltip target=".custom-upload-btn" content="Upload" position="bottom" />
        <Tooltip target=".custom-cancel-btn" content="Clear" position="bottom" />

        <FileUpload 
          ref={fileUploadRef} 
          name="demo[]" 
          url="/api/upload" 
          multiple 
          accept="image/*" 
          maxFileSize={10000000}
          onUpload={onTemplateUpload} 
          onSelect={onTemplateSelect} 
          onError={onTemplateClear} 
          onClear={onTemplateClear}
          headerTemplate={headerTemplate} 
          itemTemplate={itemTemplate} 
          emptyTemplate={emptyTemplate}
          chooseOptions={chooseOptions} 
          uploadOptions={uploadOptions} 
          cancelOptions={cancelOptions} 
        />

        {uploadMethod && <div className='footer'>
          <input className='btn btn-success' type='button' defaultValue={'Submit'} onClick={() => handleImagesSubmit()} disabled={loading} />
        </div>}
      </div>
    </PrimeReactProvider>
  );
}

export default App;


My Flask Code :
import os
import io
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from flask import Flask, request, send_file, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image as ExcelImage

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 1000 * 1024 * 1024  # 1 GB

# Load the saved models
model_paths = {
    'weave': './saved_model/model.h5',
    'shade': './saved_model/model_shade.h5',
    'majcat': './saved_model/model_majcat.h5',
    'lycra': './saved_model/model_lycra.h5',
    'fabweight': './saved_model/model_fabweight.h5',
    'collar': './saved_model/model_collar.h5',
    'yarn': './saved_model/model_yarn.h5',
    'fab': './saved_model/model_fab.h5',
    'fab2': './saved_model/model_fab2.h5',
    'weave1': './saved_model/model_weave1.h5',
    'weave3': './saved_model/model_weave3.h5',
    'placketchanging': './saved_model/model_placketchanging.h5',
    'bltmainstyle': './saved_model/model_bltmainstyle.h5',
    'substylebelt': './saved_model/model_substylebelt.h5',
    'sleevesmainstyle': './saved_model/model_sleevesmainstyle.h5',
    'btfold': './saved_model/model_btfold.h5',
    'set': './saved_model/model_set.h5',
    'neckband': './saved_model/model_neckband.h5',
    'pocket': './saved_model/model_pocket.h5',
    'fit': './saved_model/model_fit.h5',
    'pattern': './saved_model/model_pattern.h5',
    'length': './saved_model/model_length.h5',
    'mainstyle': './saved_model/model_mainstyle.h5',
    'dcsubstyle': './saved_model/model_dcsubstyle.h5',
    'dcedgeloop': './saved_model/model_dcedgeloop.h5',
    'btnmainmvgr': './saved_model/model_btnmainmvgr.h5',
    'substylebtnclr': './saved_model/model_substylebtnclr.h5',
    'zip': './saved_model/model_zip.h5',
    'zipcol': './saved_model/model_zipcol.h5',
    'addacc': './saved_model/model_addacc.h5',
    'acccol': './saved_model/model_acccol.h5',
    'printtype': './saved_model/model_printtype.h5',
    'printplacement': './saved_model/model_printplacement.h5',
    'printstyle': './saved_model/model_printstyle.h5',
    'patches': './saved_model/model_patches.h5',
    'patchtype': './saved_model/model_patchtype.h5',
    'embroidery': './saved_model/model_embroidery.h5',
    'embtype': './saved_model/model_embtype.h5',
    'placement': './saved_model/model_placement.h5',
    'addacc1': './saved_model/model_addacc1.h5',
    'addwash': './saved_model/model_addwash.h5',
    'addwashcolor': './saved_model/model_addwashcolor.h5'
}

models = {key: load_model(path) for key, path in model_paths.items()}

# Load the mappings
def load_mappings(directory):
    mappings = {}
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith('.json'):
            with open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'r') as file:
                mapping_name = filename.split('.')[0]
                mappings[mapping_name] = json.load(file)
    return mappings

mappings = load_mappings('mappings')

# Function to preprocess image
def preprocess_image(image):
    image = image.resize((224, 224))
    image_array = np.array(image)
    image_array = np.expand_dims(image_array, axis=0)
    image_array = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(image_array)
    return image_array

# Function to get image features using ResNet-50
def get_image_features(image_array):
    resnet_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, pooling='avg')
    features = resnet_model.predict(image_array)
    return features

# Function to map the predicted indices to labels
def mapToLabels(index, mappings):
    return mappings.get(str(index), "Unknown")

# Function to predict attributes for a given image
def predict_attributes(image):
    image_array = preprocess_image(image)
    image_features = get_image_features(image_array)

    predictions = {}
    for attr, model in models.items():
        prediction = model.predict([image_array, image_features])
        label = mapToLabels(np.argmax(prediction, axis=1)[0], mappings.get(attr, {}))
        predictions[attr] = label

    return predictions

# Function to save images and predictions to Excel
def save_predictions_to_excel(predictions, images):
    columns = ['Filename'] + [f'{attr.capitalize()} Label' for attr in models.keys()]
    df = pd.DataFrame(predictions, columns=columns)

    output = io.BytesIO()
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Predictions')

        workbook = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets['Predictions']

        # Set column width to fit content including heading length
        for col in worksheet.columns:
            max_length = 0
            column = col[0].column_letter  # Get the column name
            for cell in col:
                try:
                    if cell.row == 1:  # Include header length
                        length = len(str(cell.value))
                    else:
                        length = len(str(cell.value))
                    if length > max_length:
                        max_length = length
                except:
                    pass
            adjusted_width = (max_length + 2)
            worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width

        for idx, (filename, img) in enumerate(images.items()):
            try:
                img.thumbnail((100, 100))
                image_stream = io.BytesIO()
                img.save(image_stream, format='PNG')
                image_stream.seek(0)
                excel_img = ExcelImage(image_stream)
                cell_location = f'A{idx + 2}'
                worksheet.add_image(excel_img, cell_location)
                worksheet.row_dimensions[idx + 2].height = 100
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing image {filename}: {e}")

    output.seek(0)
    return output



@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if request.content_length > app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH']:
        return jsonify({'error': 'File too large'}), 413

@app.route('/upload-images', methods=['POST'])
def upload_images():
    images = request.files.getlist('images')
    predictions = []
    image_data = {}

    for image in images:
        try:
            img = Image.open(image)
            pred_labels = predict_attributes(img)
            predictions.append((image.filename, *pred_labels.values()))
            image_data[image.filename] = img
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing image {image.filename}: {e}")
            predictions.append((image.filename, *["Unknown"] * len(models)))
            image_data[image.filename] = None

    excel_file = save_predictions_to_excel(predictions, image_data)
    return send_file(excel_file, download_name='predictions.xlsx', as_attachment=True)

@app.route('/uploadpath', methods=['POST'])
def uploadPath():
    folder_path = request.form.get('path')
    if not folder_path:
        return jsonify({'error': 'No folder path provided'}), 400

    if not os.path.isdir(folder_path):
        return jsonify({'error': 'Provided path is not a directory'}), 400

    image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path, f))]
    predictions = []
    image_data = {}

    for image_file in image_files:
        if image_file.lower().endswith(('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif')):
            try:
                with open(os.path.join(folder_path, image_file), 'rb') as img_file:
                    img = Image.open(img_file)
                    pred_labels = predict_attributes(img)
                    predictions.append((image_file, *pred_labels.values()))
                    image_data[image_file] = img
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing image {image_file}: {e}")
                predictions.append((image_file, *["Unknown"] * len(models)))
                image_data[image_file] = None

    excel_file = save_predictions_to_excel(predictions, image_data)
    output_folder = 'output'
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)
    backup_file_path = os.path.join(output_folder, 'predictions.xlsx')
    with open(backup_file_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(excel_file.getvalue())
    return send_file(excel_file, download_name='predictions.xlsx', as_attachment=True)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return "This is an API for similar detection"

@app.errorhandler(413)
def request_entity_too_large(error):
    return jsonify({'error': 'File too large'}), 413

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 1000 * 1024 * 1024  # 1 GB
    CORS(app)
    app.run(debug=True)



Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism for integrating
applications. CORS defines a way for client web applications that are
loaded in one domain to interact with resources in a different domain.

To handle CORS there are multiple ways:

If you are running frontend and backend on different machines then try running them on the same machine.
If you are already running them on the same machine you can download CORS extension in Chrome. Once downloaded activate it and it should solve the error.
If you are using nginx/reverse-proxy then you will have to allow CORS there specifically under header section.

